# Passing an instance with list to an API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

There is the complete code of the test.
When posting JSON data to the API, the instance person is null.
Can any one tell me why

Model

```
public class Diploma
{
    public int PeronId { get; set; }
    public string Tile { get; set; }
    public string Organism { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public List<Diploma> Diplomas { get; set; }
    public Person()
    {
        Diplomas = new List<Diploma>();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public class PersonnesController : ApiController
{
    private const string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";

    // POST : Person
    [HttpPost]
    public int Post([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        bool res = false;
        int id;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert dbo.personnes (Name, Function) output INSERTED.ID values (@name, @function)", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nam", person.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@function", person.Function);
            connection.Open();

            id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            foreach (Diploma diploma in person.Diplomas)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert diplomes values(@id, @title, @organism)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", diploma.Tile);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@organism", diploma.Organism);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm testing with RESTClient for Firefox,

In header section:

```
Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Show us what you are POSTing to this endpoint.

Comment: `{"Name":"my name","Function":"my function" "diplomas":[{"title":"diploma 1", "organism":"university 1"},{"title":"diploma 2", "organism":"university 2"}]}`

Comment: no changes. person still null

Comment: There is a comma missing in your JSON, before "diplomas"

Comment: @Nkosi, yes, i'm making a post resquest and i spicify the header as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: @andynormancx, the comma is added, still null

Comment: @alisriti Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Current  example posted should work by default so there are details missing that make us unable to provide an accurate assessment. The back and forth in the comments demonstrate that.

Comment: @Nkosi, post update, the complete code is provided. thanks guys

Comment: @alisriti include the client side code used to make the request. you mentioned rest client.

Comment: the test example is
`{
    "Name": "my name",
    "Function": "my function",
    "diplomas": [{
        "title": "diploma 1",
        "organism": "university 1"
    }, {
        "title": "diploma 2",
        "organism": "university 2"
    }]
}`

Comment: @Nkosi, i'm testing with a REST client. no client side code yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being sent using the wrong `Content-Type`.

It was indicated that data was sent using `Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

while the shown data is *JSON*

```
{ "Name": "my name", "Function": "my function", "diplomas": [{ "title": "diploma 1", "organism": "university 1" }, { "title": "diploma 2", "organism": "university 2" }] }
```

which would use `Content-type : application/json` content type

The model binder was unable to parse the content using the provided content type, so it default the model to *null*.